# Show Only Future Posts in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way I can create a loop in Jekyll that shows only posts starting today and into the future in chronological order? I'm making a GitHub Pages site for a meetup group and I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: I think you need a time machine to do what you want ;) Are you asking how to display the most recent posts at the top, or do you want to hide all posts before a certain date?

Comment: I want to hide all posts before yesterday. It's for meetups, so all events will have to happen either today or the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code below can do the trick:

```
{% assign curDate = site.time | date: '%s' %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% assign postStartDate = post.date | date: '%s' %}
    {% if postStartDate >= curDate %}
        Post datas here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But you will need to "build" your site every day as Github only updates when there is a push to your repository.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I've set up a cron job to push a dummy commit to GitHub every day as well.